# Network "monitoring" for Mac OS infrastructure

Tags: mac-osx, network-monitoring, munin

Is there any free (and preferably open source, but not mandatory) solution to know how much bandwidth each macintosh is using.

I have munin on a Debian, monitoring multiple linux servers, but I cannot get any network usage monitoring on the macs with it. Only disk usage and load average plugins are working. Which is absolutely not what I need.

Any suggestions other than munin? Or even a network usage munin plugin working on Mac OS?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Another option if you have a manageable switch would be to port-mirror the inside interface of your firewall, then send that to a system running something like [nfsen](http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/Installing+nfsen).  This is much heavier weight tool than a snmp counter grapher like Cacti is, but in my experience the first question after "how much bandwidth are we using?" is always "...doing what?"  nfsen can help you answer those questions.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be feasible to get stats from your switch to graph? That's the most reliable way, and probably hassle-free in the long run for management. It also doesn't get colored by software glitches, configuration issues, etc. on the client if the client is monitoring itself.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean SNMP?

Comment: Yes, SNMP. Unless your switches support some other interface, but SNMP is the most common I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

[Surplus meter](http://osrevolution.com/os-tutorial/mac-os-x-bandwidth-monitoring-surplus-meter) made by SkoobySoft

**Edited to add (based on your comment)**:  What kind of networking hardware are you using?  It's probably simpler and less expensive to do it here as opposed to software running on your OS.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear. I mean a centralized interface. I cannot afford to go on each Mac. That's the whole point.